# How can I let Sublime Text 3 run export/import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

The version of my sublime text is 3126.

I wanna to use **Ctri+b** to run the javascript,so I create a new build system setting to run js based on nodejs like this:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

**But import and export is not avaliable in nodejs-v6(6.10.2).**

What should I do? How to change the setting?